# Node Postgres (pg) library can't find relation of table

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I have a Postgres DB that I need to modify. It is in my localhost. I am trying to use Node Postgres for it, but I am missing something out from the document.

```
const client = new Client({
  user: 'postgreadmin',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'testdb',
  password: 'somepassword',
  port: 5433,
})

client.query('SELECT * FROM User', function(err, result) {
  console.log
  (result);
 client.end();
});
```

The result shows return 'postgreadmin' as the user. Which is somewhat confusing. My database users should contain users like 'peter', 'mary' etc. The query seems to be running on the Postgres' configuration, and not on the db tables itself.

I tried other tables and the error is "no relation Merchant found'. I am not sure how to connect to the tables. My tables are under the schema call 'public'. So my question is do i need to specify the in pg's configuration to connect to the schema 'public'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is a function that returns the current database user, so `select user` will return the database user (and `select * from user` will as well).

If you **did** create a table with that name you need to use double quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM "User"
```

Note that quoted identifiers are case-sensitive. `"User"` is a different name than `"user"` or `"USER"`. Check your database for the correct spelling. The same is probably true for `"Merchant"`

I strongly recommend you rename the table to something that is not a reserved keyword and does not collide with any internal function name.

For more details, see the manual:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Thanks, it is the double quotation marks that work. I realized that if my table has capital letter, i will need double quotation marks when selecting it.